# Map controller and view (Suit CRM 7.7.8)

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am very new to SugarCRM (SuitCRM 7.7.8). I could create a controller and could echo some strings in it. I wanted to make that value in a view file. I got confused whether I should use some js files or some tpl view file. 
This is my code:

```
<?php
class MymoduleController extends SugarController {
    //Can now put actions here
    public function action_convert(){
        echo "Hello world!";
        //return true;
        exit;
    }
}
```

How can I map the controller  to a view file.

Comment: What you want to do , please explain then we can provide you the solutions.

Comment: Hi, I was confused how to pass a value to the view file. I could execute the controller function i have created. it just prints 'Hello world!' But i want that string in a view file. How the values are passing to a view file and how these files are mapped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller action method add the following:

```
$this->view = 'EditView'
```

Change the 'EditView' to the view you wish to use. The built in MVC stuff is kept in **include/MVC** and the **include/ListView**, **include/EditView**, and **include/MVC/DetailView**.

If you take a look at say **module/Accounts/views**. You can see how views are implemented. It is best to create your code  in the **custom/modules/[module]** folder. As this ensures that your changes will not be overwritten when you upgrade SuiteCRM.

You should separate your html with your view using tpls.
if you add the following in the display method of your view:

```
function display(){
    $template = new Sugar_Smarty();
    $template->assign('APP', $app_strings);
    $template->assign('MOD', $mod_string);
    echo $template->fetch('include/ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl');
}
```

you can load your custom views.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I am going through the source code and trying to figure it out...